# Running hadoop for processing sources in full sky maps

Tags: hadoop, astronomy

I have few tens of full sky maps, in binary format (FITS) of about 600MB each.

For each sky map I already have a catalog of the position of few thousand sources, i.e. stars, galaxies, radio sources.

For each source I would like to:

- open the full sky map
- extract the relevant section, typically 20MB or less
- run some statistics on them
- aggregate the outputs to a catalog

I would like to run `hadoop`, possibly using `python` via the `streaming` interface, to process them in parallel.

I think the input to the mapper should be each record of the catalogs,
then the `python` mapper can open the full sky map, do the processing and print the output to `stdout`.

1. Is this a reasonable approach?
2. If so, I need to be able to configure `hadoop` so that a full sky map is copied locally to the nodes that are processing one of its sources. How can I achieve that?
3. Also, what is the best way to feed the input data to `hadoop`? for each source I have a reference to the full sky map, latitude and longitude

Answer (score 2):

Though it doesn't sound like a few tens of your sky maps are a very big data set, I've used Hadoop successfully as an simple way to write distributed applications/scripts.

For the problem you describe, I would try implementing a solution with Pydoop, and specifically [Pydoop Script](http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/pydoop_script.html) (full disclaimer:  I'm one of the Pydoop developers).

You could set up a job that takes as input the list of sections of the sky map that you want to process, serialized in some sort of text format with one record per line.  Each map task should process one of these; you can achieve this split easily with the standard NLineInputFormat.

You don't need to copy the sky map locally to all the nodes as long as the map tasks can access the file system on which it is stored.  Using the pydoop.hdfs module, the map function can read the section of the sky map that it needs to process (given the coordinates it received as input) and then emit the statistics as you were saying so that they can be aggregated in the reducer.  pydoop.hdfs can read from both "standard" mounted file systems and HDFS.

Though the problem domain is totally unrelated, this application may serve as an example:

```
https://github.com/ilveroluca/seal/blob/master/seal/dist_bcl2qseq.py#L145
```

It uses the same strategy, preparing a list of "coordinates" to be processed, serializing them to a file, and then launching a simple pydoop job that takes that file as input.

Hope that helps!